# Binary outcome, different trial #s across low N?

Tags: r, statistics, analysis

I have a sample of 4 individuals, all who have a varying number of trials (I work with a special population so what I get is what I get!)
The outcome is a binary yes/no

I want to know:

1. did the total sample select yes more often than chance?
2. did each individual select yes more often than chance?

Here is dummy data in R.

```
SbjEL <- data.frame(Sbj = c('EL'), 
TrialNum = c(1:12), 
Choice = c(0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1, NA))

SbjKZ <- data.frame(Sbj = c('KZ'), 
TrialNum = c(1:12), 
Choice = c(0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1, 1))

SbjMA <- data.frame(Sbj = c('MA'), 
TrialNum = c(1:12), 
Choice = c(0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1, 1))

SbjTC <- data.frame(Sbj = c('EL'), 
TrialNum = c(1:12), 
Choice = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1, NA,NA,NA, NA))
```

For a different experiment with the same sample, I had more trials and did a one sample t test for the sample, and a binomial distribution to see what # of trials of Yes would be higher than chance.

```
# Did group select YES more than chance? --> 43 yes/48
Response_v <- c(21,22)
  
t.test(Response_v, mu = 12, alternative = "two.sided")  

# How many YES selections would be more often than chance?
# 24 trials were completed --> 21 yes / 24
binom.test(21, 24, 1/2)
```

My issue is this starts to fall apart when I get down to 8-12 trials.

Any ideas? I am lost

Answer (score 0):

A t-test is not appropriate here for either Q1 or Q2. With large samples you can use some approximations, but your counts are very small. So, you’re on the right track with the binomial test, but not the t-test.

For your Q1: you first ought to decide how the subjects are assumed to relate to each other. Are you pretty confident that each is providing an estimate of the same Bernoulli probability, p? Or instead, a-priori do you want to allow the possibility that subjects have different p’s? There are further questions to answer, overlapping with those you need to consider for Q2.

For your Q2: The exact method of choice depends on a number of things: For example, do you want to incorporate prior information (e.g. using historical data as a reference)? If not, there are purely frequentist methods to use off the shelf. Next, do you expect the yes/no’s to be independent, or are they more like a ‘signal’ in which the order matters? Third, is it possible that there is a mixture of Bernoullis for any of the subjects? And so on. These questions can be considered through software such as that found at [www.datatrie.com/advisor](https://www.datatrie.com/advisor)

Comment: Q1: I want the subjects to have the same p-value, I don't have any reason to believe they would behave differently at baseline from each other. 

Q2: I do not want to use historical data, I only have this data from them, and I don't think I really have enough data to look at hysteresis of their selections. I think each trial is independent, but I think their selection will be biased in a certain way (I think they will show a preference for one option or the other), the order does not matter.

Thanks for sharing that link, I will have to look into it!

Comment: It sounds like you are not 100% sure that the test subjects have the same p, but do not want to model them as separate. Therefore, run the binomial test four times, and fuse the resulting p-values. The method of choice for fusing the p-values again depends on the answer to several questions. The tool at the above link will help you choose among Stouffer's Z score, Fisher's method, the harmonic p-value, etc.